# Can we use metadata columns to tag pages in the 'Pages' library (SharePoint 2013 Online)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-page, metadata, tagging

I have added a metadata column to the 'Pages' library to tag the pages in SharePoint 2013 Online. But when I tried to add a tag for page by editing the page properties my column is not shown there.
So Can we use metadata columns to tag pages in the 'Pages' library?

Comment: Make sure you added the column to the correct content types.

Comment: Thanks Amal. It worked when I add it to the CT other than the library. :)

Comment: Ok. I posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple content types associated with the library.

Make sure you added the column to the correct content types.

1. Open pages library settings
2. Open the content types
3. Add new site column